# Bitmap editor to make game sprites in Linux?

Tags: linux, open-source, images, pixel-graphics

We would like to draw textures and skins for games like Minetest and Minecraft. What do you recommend?
Feature preferences (in order of importance):

1. Similar to software used by experienced artists for such games.
2. The subject of tutorial(s) for drawing game graphics
3. Works on current Linux
4. A live preview that updates while we edit a magnified view
5. Free/Libre/Open source
6. Color picker
7. Line, border and fill tools
8. Actively maintained

We have looked at this list, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Raster_graphics_editors_for_Linux but we don't yet know which of those apps have features 1 and 2.

This list looks closer to the mark:
 http://alternativeto.net/software/grafx2/?platform=linux

Related questions:

- [What pixel graphics program supports creating seamless tiles?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/204/what-pixel-graphics-program-supports-creating-seamless-tiles) (answers are Windows and Mac apps)
- [General-purpose sprite manager](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/general-purpose-sprite-manager)
- [Game development content pipeline/toolchain?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4153/game-development-content-pipeline-toolchain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [aseprite](http://www.aseprite.org/), an [opensource](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/#license) (see [their faq](http://www.aseprite.org/faq/#If-Aseprite-is-open-source-how-is-that-you-are-selling-it)) pixel art editor [which supports](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite#introduction):

> - Sprites are composed by layers & frames (as separated concepts).
> - Supported color modes: RGBA, Indexed (palettes up to 256 colors), and Grayscale.
> - Load/save sequence of PNG files and GIF animations (also FLC, FLI, JPG, BMP, PCX, TGA).
> - Export/import animations to/from Sprite Sheets.
> - **Tiled drawing mode**, useful to draw patterns and textures.
> - Undo/Redo for every operation.
> - **Mini-editor** with real-time animation preview.
> - Multiple editors support.
> - **Pixel art specific tools** like filled Contour & Polygon.
> - Onion skinning

Comment: Thanks - this looks great. I will let you know how this works for us. Hopefully I can customize the mini-editor to show an actual size preview.

Comment: Update: versions prior to Sep 1, 2016 are open source. Updates since then have a shared source proprietary EULA: https://dev.aseprite.org/2016/09/01/new-source-code-license/

Comment: For a maintained Libre fork, see: https://libresprite.github.io/